# Авторизация на сайте при помощи сертификата

Tags: delphi, ssl, indy, delphi-10-tokyo

У меня есть пользовательский сертификат. sert.cer. Мне нужно авторизоваться на сайте и скачать файлы.  я его при помощи операции `openssl x509 -inform der -in sert.cer -out certificate.pem`  преобразовал  в .pem (в примерах везде pem поключают).  так же у меня есть корневой сертификат `D:\br.so-ups.ru(GOST-2012).cer`. Но при запросе `Get` 
`zHTTP.Get('https://br.so-ups.ru:444/webapi/public/ssl/LoginByCert.aspx');`

Вылетает ошибка

> Project LisTLoad.exe raised exception class EIdOSSLLoadingCertError with message 'Could not load certificate.
> error:0609E09C:digital envelope routines:PKEY_SET_TYPE:unsupported algorithm'.

```
  zHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(aHTTP);

  zHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;
  zHandler.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvSSLv2, sslvSSLv3, sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];
  zHandler.SSLOptions.CertFile := 'D:\certificate.pem';
  zHandler.SSLOptions.KeyFile := 'D:\certificate.pem';
  zHandler.SSLOptions.RootCertFile := 'D:\br.so-ups.ru(GOST-2012).cer';
  zHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;
  with aHTTP do
  begin
    Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0';
    Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml');
    Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64;Trident/7.0 rv:11.0) like Gecko');
    Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Connection', 'Keep-Alive');
    Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('DNT', '1');
    Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Referer', 'https://br.so-ups.ru/signin');
    Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Host', 'https://br.so-ups.ru');
    Request.BasicAuthentication := False;

    CookieManager := IdCookie1;
    AllowCookies := True;
    HandleRedirects := True;
    IOHandler := zHandler;
    if CheckBox2.Checked = True then
    begin
      ProxyParams.ProxyPort := proxy_port;
      ProxyParams.ProxyServer := proxy_server;
      ProxyParams.ProxyUsername := proxy_login;
      ProxyParams.ProxyPassword := proxy_password;
    end;
    ReadTimeout := 100000000;
  end;
```

В браузере авторизация через пользовательский сертификат проходит нормалотно

Comment: @Kromster  Embarcadero® RAD Studio 10.2

Comment: «В браузере» — в каком и с какими плагинами? По умолчанию ни браузеры, ни openssl, ни delphi не поддерживают ГОСТ-шифрование

Comment: @andreymal браузер IE 11. Про плагины не понял. Так же на пк установлен крипро про

Comment: Ну вот только благодаря КриптоПро и работает. Никто по умолчанию не поддерживает ГОСТ-шифрование, соответственно нужно искать криптопро-плагины для delphi или что-то типа того